# Auto Increment for Sub Id

Tags: auto-increment

I need to create a tiles table that has a structure like this for http://www.myownmealplanner.com:

```
id user_id sub_tile_id
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   2   1
5   2   2
6   2   3
7   3   1
8   3   2
9   3   3
```

etc. 
I can't just create new tables for new users because I'm using cakephp and that would require new models, views, and controllers for every new table. How do I get the sub_tile_id to auto_increment starting at every new user id?

Comment: After dropping the id field, I tried both of these and got syntax errors
ALTER TABLE `tiles` MODIFY COLUMN `sub_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT WHERE `user_id` = 2;
UPDATE TABLE `tiles` MODIFY COLUMN `sub_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT WHERE `user_id` =2;

Comment: For other stunts I've tried I've gotten the following error: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used

Comment: This didn't work
CREATE TABLE `tiles` (  
 `sub_tile` ENUM('1','2','3') NOT NULL,
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,  
 `user_id` INT(22)
 )